# 1998 VW Beetle - Clutch and Electrical Issues

Tags: electrical, vw, clutch, clutch-cylinder, beetle

I have a 98 VW BEETLE.

I had to change my clutch all the way from the master cylinder to the clutch pedal. Still have no clutch. Then when I tried to start my car all the lights come on even radio but wont even turn over.

All of the lights maybe on but no-one is home kinda thing.

I tried resetting the comp but still no cranking. What can I do?

Comment: By no clutch, do you mean the pedal goes to the floor with little effort and without releasing the clutch?  Are you sure the clutch is bled 100%?  As for the not starting, look for a clutch safety switch.

Answer (score 1):

These could be seperate issues all together perhaps, the clutch does sound interesting, you might have missed something in the process of changing you're clutch? Also don't forget (I think) about the clutch slave (Not sure if VW beetles have one.. but I'd assume most if not all manual cars do).. Just check it over, making sure that everything is in its correct place/position.

As for the lights/turning over.. make sure all items that use power to start are turned off (e.g. headlights, interior lights, radio, etc..) If the problem persists, check (maybe, but unlikely) your ground? As well as remembering to check the charge of the battery.

(Note: I do not own a VW, this is my knowledge of what I would do in the same situation. I do not hold responsibility for damage or harm that happens to the vehicle or yourself, this is just what I would do in the same position)